# библиотека prop-types

Tags: reactjs

Вопрос мой, вероятно, обусловлен моим плохим пониманием подключения библиотек. В index.html файле я подключил prop-types через CDN. Тем не менее в App.js

```
News.propTypes = {
  data: React.PropTypes.array.isRequired
};
```

не дает возможности получать оповещения в консоли об ошибке ("Failed PropTypes и т.д."). Заранее спасибо!

App.js

```
var my_news = [
  {
    author: "Alex Pechkin",
    text: "On thursday, 4th september..."
  },
  {
    author: "Just Vasya",
    text: "$ shuld be 35 rus I guess"
  },
  {
    author: "guest",
    text: "Download for free - http//:localhost3000"
  }
]



var News = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
    var data = this.props.data;
    var newsTemplate;

    if (data.length > 0) {
    newsTemplate = data.map(function(item, index) {
      return (
        <div key={index}>
          <Article data={item}/>
        </div>
      )
      })
    } else {
      newsTemplate = <p>"Sorry we don't have any news"</p>
    }

      return (
        <div className="news">
          {newsTemplate}
          <strong className={"news__count " + (data.length>0 ? "" : "none")}>We have {data.length} news</strong>
        </div>
      );
  }
});

News.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

var Article = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    var author =  this.props.data.author,
        text =  this.props.data.text;

    return (
      <div className = "article">
        <p className="news__author">{author}:</p>
        <p className="news__text">{text}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
})

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <h3>Новости</h3>
        <News {ЗДЕСЬ ДОЛЖНЫ ПЕРЕДАВАТЬСЯ PROPS} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});



ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>React [RU] Tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">Привет, я #root</div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prop-types/15.6.0/prop-types.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="js/react/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/react/react-dom.min.js"></script> -->
    <!-- <script src="./js/react/browser.min.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/babel" src="./js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
var my_news = [{
    author: "Alex Pechkin",
    text: "On thursday, 4th september..."
  },
  {
    author: "Just Vasya",
    text: "$ shuld be 35 rus I guess"
  },
  {
    author: "guest",
    text: "Download for free - http//:localhost3000"
  }
]



var News = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var data = this.props.data;
    var newsTemplate;

    if (data.length > 0) {
      newsTemplate = data.map(function(item, index) {
        return ( <
          div key = {
            index
          } >
          <
          Article data = {
            item
          }
          /> <
          /div>
        )
      })
    } else {
      newsTemplate = < p > "Sorry we don't have any news" < /p>
    }

    return ( <
      div className = "news" > {
        newsTemplate
      } <
      strong className = {
        "news__count " + (data.length > 0 ? "" : "none")
      } > We have {
        data.length
      }
      news < /strong> <
      /div>
    );
  }
});

News.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

var Article = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var author = this.props.data.author,
      text = this.props.data.text;

    return ( <
      div className = "article" >
      <
      p className = "news__author" > {
        author
      }: < /p> <
      p className = "news__text" > {
        text
      } < /p> <
      /div>
    )
  }
})

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return ( <
      div className = "app" >
      <
      h3 > Новости < /h3> <
      News data = {
        my_news
      }
      /> <
      /div>
    );
  }
});



ReactDOM.render( <
  App / > ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>React [RU] Tutorial</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root">Привет, я #root</div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prop-types/15.6.0/prop-types.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="js/react/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/react/react-dom.min.js"></script> -->
  <!-- <script src="./js/react/browser.min.js"></script> -->
  <script type="text/babel" src="./js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PropTypes была вынесена из react в отдельную библиотеку начиная с версии 15.5

> React.PropTypes has moved into a different package since React v15.5. Please use the prop-types library instead. https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Поэтому уберите `React.` из вызова

```
News.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};
```

Comment: Дмитрий, спасибо, но даже при такой записи и создании ошибки в передаче props компоненту, в консоли браузера пишет только "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined", но ничего относящегося к типу передаваемых props нет. Может, помимо cdn требуются еще какие-то действия?

Comment: а data точно массив и передается в props?

Comment: и в инструментах разработчика перейдите из сообщения об ошибке куда она ведет. Где собственно проверяется эта длина

Comment: Дмитрий, добавил сверху app.js и index.html

Comment: Также подписал, где искусственно создана ошибка

Comment: а в `{ЗДЕСЬ ДОЛЖНЫ ПЕРЕДАВАТЬСЯ PROPS}` что реально передается?

Comment: data = {my_news}

Comment: возможно, проблема в ссылке на cdn? Там несколько вариантов было.

Comment: Преобразовал в сниппет. Код работает и выдает список

Comment: И я так и не понял, в каком месте выскакивала ошибка

Comment: Возможно, я неточно объяснил. Я специально убрал data={my_news}, чтобы prop-types выдала в консоли ошибку "Failed PropTypes, required prop "data.author" ... Но у меня в консоли такой ошибки нет, а это означает, если я правильно понимаю, что prop_types свою работу не делает

Comment: `убрал data={my_news}`, а ну тогда все правильно, внутри у вас проверка data.length, а data у вас undefined, вот и выскакивает ошибка. Для проверки сделайте внутри локальную `data = []`

Comment: Дмитрий, спасибо большое!